# InflateException Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment with ScrollViews

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have really tried every suggestion out there for this problem, but was unable to solve my problem.

So I am getting an exception `Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment`. It seems to me pretty obvious that on line #2, that is a Scrollview, the inflating of the view is failing.

My code with explanation of my goal. I am using AccountAuthenticators by which I check whether an account exists with my desired account type, so far so good. If there is no account in the system I create a new explicit intent to start the `LoginActivity` which hosts a `LoginFragment`, whereby I get this exception.

By similar problems on Stackoverflow I have read so far, my Activity supports Fragments (I use `ActionBarActivity` which extends `FragmentActivity`). -> `public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity` -> `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`.

My LoginActivity layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_login"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.anuragajwani.whomsapp.activity.LoginFragment"
    tools:context="com.anuragajwani.whomsapp.activity.LoginFragment" />
```

I did try changing `android:name` to `class` as some suggested, but they also pointed out it should work regardless. Also I have other fragments in the system working fine using `android:name`.

Now here is where I believe my problem lies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Header -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
                android:contentDescription="Brightpearl Logo"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Header -->

        <!-- Login Form -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Datacenter -->
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/data_centre_spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/data_centres"
                android:prompt="@string/data_centre_prompt"/>
            <!-- account label -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Account"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/accountAccessAccount"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
            <!-- username label -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Email"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/accountAccessEmail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
            <!-- password label -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Password"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/accountAccessPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:password="true"/>
            <!-- Login button -->
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:text="Login"/>
            <!-- Future link to prodeo website -->
            <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginTop="40dip"-->
                <!--android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"-->
                <!--android:text="Create new Prodeo account"/>-->

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Login Form End -->


        <!-- Footer Start add brightpearl partner logo -->
        <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
            <!-- -->
        <!--</LinearLayout>-->
        <!-- Footer End -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.ScrollView>
```

Line #2 I'm guessing has something to do with ScrollView not playing nice with previous versions. I changed `ScrollView` to `android.support.v4.widget.ScrollView` just for the sake of trying, but no results.

My LoginFragment ->

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: changed back to ScrollView and it works on Android 5.0.1 and it works. Still would love more info and retrocompatibility to work.

Comment: `ScrollView` is available since api level 1. Change   `android.support.v4.widget.ScrollView`  with  `ScrollView`. If you still have problem post the stacktrace of the exception

Comment: Thanks BlackBelt, as per my previous update that is what I did, although I am running against Android 5.0.1 where previously I was running against 4.4.4, I'll try running it against 4.4.4 once I get the Login page design correctly.